# Weird outlines when changing Pages in Flutter

Tags: android, ios, flutter

I got these weird lines when I'm changing the pages in my flutter app. I'm pretty new to flutter and was completely confused when the lines also appeared in production mode.

Does someone know what these are and how I can remove them?

[image]

I rebuild the app and tried to disable debug mode but nothing worked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might be having `const Placeholder();` on top of the stack which is the root cause for the cross lines, just remove that widget & you'll be fine. If you don't find it on the current page search for it throughout the project with the help of the "ctrl + shift + F" short key.

Comment: dude thank you so much. I'm such a dumbass. There was a Placeholder in a FutureBuilder. You saved me dude :D

Comment: sure, any time dude. Just mark the question as resolved & give an upvote if possible, thanks.